# RDLC report not showing data when deploy to IIS

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, rdlc

I have develop report its working fine on local environment on visual studio
[image]

but when deploy on server it look like:

[image]

**Why application display empty  report after depolyment**

Comment: Did you check if it is connecting to the correct  database

Comment: yes it is connecting

Comment: can you also share the IIS version in your development environment. I assume on server it's iis 7 as mentioned in tag?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the RDLC file to bin folder and then deploy again

Another one just to try whether that works or not you can copy RDLC file to the Application folder.

Hope this helps